# What is the `(... && TraitsOf())` mean in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand this C++ syntax:

```
    constexpr auto all_deps_type_set =
        (... | TraitsOf(types::type_c<HaversackTs>).all_deps);
```

What does the `(...|` part mean?

Example: https://github.com/google/hotels-template-library/blob/master/haversack/haversack_test_util.h

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HaversackTs` is a [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack), which means it contains some variable number of types given to the template. `...` expands a template parameter pack, using a given binary operator (in our case, the bitwise `|`) to fold over it. So if, in a particular instantiation of this template, `HaversackTs` happened to be `int, std::string`, then that line would mean

```
constexpr auto all_deps_type_set =
    (TraitsOf(types::type_c<int>).all_deps | TraitsOf(types::type_c<std::string>).all_deps);
```

The right-hand side is expanded separately for each type in the parameter pack, and the results are combined using `|`. This generalizes naturally to more than two arguments by simply applying `|` between each one.

Comment: You should mention https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold for the different ways `...` can be used to fold a parameter pack. The location of the `...` determines the order of evaluation.